# Can I make "bash -x" not print the "+ " prefix?

Tags: bash, command-line, instrumentation, verbose

When I invoke bash with the `-x` option, it prints each command before it is executed. However - the commands are printed with a "+ " prefix.

Is there a way to get it to print the commands, but *without* this prefix? With `-x` or without it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can customize the prefix when using `bash -x` by setting the variable PS4. So in your .bashrc, you could have something like this:

```
export PS4=''
```

Or, if you want to debug something, let it print the line number like this:

```
export PS4='[ $LINENO ] '
```

Answer (score 1):

Insert as the first line :

```
set -v
```

then run it without -x

Comment: `set -v` doesn't print the same thing as `set -x` -- it prints commands *before* variables etc are expanded. For example, if you have `var="value"` and the command `echo {1..2} "$var"`, with `set -x` it prints `+ echo 1 2 value`, but with `set -v` it prints `echo {1..2} "$var"`.

Comment: @GordonDavisson `set -v` actuallys print the raw input *lines* as they're read; it does not print the *commands* either before or after they're expanded. Compare `for i in 1 2 3; do echo $i; done` with `set -x` and `set -v`.